# Excel 2010 (xlsm) Forms Button sometimes disappeared

Tags: vba, button, excel, excel-2010

Has anyone come across the case when using a xlsm spreadsheet in Excel 2010, the Forms Button sometimes disappeared, but then sometimes it appears again. Obviously its a bug by Microsoft but any alternative solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it is a bug in Excel. I bet it happens whenever you change your zoom level to less or more than 100%. MS is aware of the bug, but as far as I know, they have not corrected the issue and there is nothing on the user end that we can do to fix it.

Comment: Setting zoom level to 100% does not solve the issue. But you are right that when I zoom-in/out the sheet, the buttons re-appears. Really disappointing to Microsoft on this silly UI bug......

Comment: @TsuiJohn MS has know about the bug since Office 2007 but has not been fixed. It is truly frustrating for me because I deal with a lot of forms and buttons. I try to stay away from buttons and use hyperlinks whenever I can.

Comment: Thaks Jose M. So are you adding the line "Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink()" whenever you want to execute macros with hyperlinks? That seems not convenient... 
Actually will using Excel97-03 format solves the issues? (instead of using xlsm)

Comment: @TsuiJohn It's definitely not convenient but, it helps reduce the amount of controls on the form.  I do not know if the issue also resides witn 97-03,